# Invoke server side method using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: asp.net, ajax, xmlhttprequest

how can i directly call my own server side function using XMLHttpRequest.

suppose i have one static webmethod in my aspx file then how can i call it by XMLHttpRequest. what header info i need to pass to asp.net engine and as a result asp.net engine can invoke my method and return the response back in the out going stream.

this way i need to call my server side method

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var request;

// A
// Here is the new function that is called when the user submits the form.
// This example uses POST.
function submitCallback() {
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("SearchInput").value;
    var sendStr = "name=" + inputValue;
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // B
    // Specify the POST method and send it.
    request.open("POST", "Default.aspx/Getdata");
    request.onreadystatechange = readyCallback;
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRequestHeader("IsLookup", "true");
    request.send(sendStr);
}
</script>
```

please guide me....thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are probably referring to ASP.NET Page Methods when you say *One static webmethod in my aspx file*. ASP.NET page methods (or web services for consumption in JS) uses JSON serialization for i/p and o/p. So you need to set JSON as the content type for the request and actually send the JSON string in the body i.e.

```
...
var sendStr = "{name:" + inputValue + "}";
...
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
...
request.send(sendStr);
```

Further, I will suggest you to use jquery or ASP.NET generated proxies (by ScriptManager) instead of directly coding against XmlHttpRequest. See this [article](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) for how to use jquery for calling Page methods.

Comment: @Thomas, IMO, first two lines are only ones that needs change - the rest of code that you quoted should remain as is. For troubleshooting, you should use tool such as fiddler (or Firebug on Firefox) to inspect HTTP request and response.

Comment: what is the meaning of request.setRequestHeader("IsLookup", "true"); what is IsLookup....what is the importance.

Comment: @Thomas, AFAIK, it's not a standard HTTP header and it does not have any meaning ASP.NET Ajax as well as. I was assuming that its some custom  header that you are setting to do some processing in server side code (probably HttpModule).

Answer (score 0):

I think, the easiest way will be usage of jQuery for ajax requests: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/